# How can I use EndlessGPT2.py with Google playground collab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

What command should I use for writing text input on EndlessGPT2??

I am getting "invalid syntax" error

I am using Google playground colab!!

What can I do to fix the syntax error ??

````
from google.colab import drive
import sys
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/EndlessGPT2.py')

!python EndlessGPT2.py

GPT2 Pytorch implementation by https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
Modified by @rrrffw

--text dog

SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````